# PHP make test failures

Tags: php, compilation, makefile

I'm rebuilding and upgrading PHP(5.3.2 -> 5.5.14) to match the current installation except with the addition of the pthread module.

My main question is about the seriousness of make test failures. Currently I'm sitting with 29 failures out of roughly 12,000 tests. (They are mostly DBA related and I probably just need to re compile that with different options or something). A few of the failures give a number that relates to a PHP bug case. I've visited the pages for the cases and they are all closed from a year or two ago and are for PHP 4.3 or something like that and they say the issues have been fixed.

Everything is compiling and installing just fine (I haven't started apache yet, so I don't know if it works 100%, but I've been able to run PHP scripts via php command), so do I need to worry about the failures from make test? Or are they actually resolved as the case pages say and the tests just have not been updated? (I can link actually cases if need be).

Bug Codes:

```
Bug #36436 (DBA problem with Berkeley DB4) [ext/dba/tests/bug36436.phpt]
Bug #48240 (DBA Segmentation fault dba_nextkey) [ext/dba/tests/bug48240.phpt]
Bug #49125 (Error in dba_exists C code) [ext/dba/tests/bug49125.phpt]
Bug #42298 (pcre gives bogus results with /u) [ext/pcre/tests/bug42298.phpt]
Bug #42737 (preg_split('//u') triggers a E_NOTICE with newlines[ext/pcre/tests/bug42737.phpt]
Bug #52971 (PCRE-Meta-Characters not working with utf-8) [ext/pcre/tests/bug52971.phpt]
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of a test is that is should pass.  If a test passes after a change is made, then the tester can be confident that the underlying behavior under test has not been changed as a result of the change. If a test fails after you make a change, then it means that the change caused the underlying behavior to change or break altogether.

Typically, breaking tests in the test suite and not fixing them is not a good practice, because then you are losing the value of implementing the tests in the first place.  If you are not trying to preserve the functionality then what is the point of the test in the first place?

Go back to your upgrade and see if any of those bugs are serious.  If they aren't, then consider modifying or deleting them.  It is possible that the tests failed because there are some differences between your PHP versions, or possibly because the way you upgraded the language caused a problem.